# Continuous Quaternion Rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, quaternions

I'm new to Unity, so please bear with me. I'm trying to continuously rotate a GameObject (sphere) using Quaternions, but I haven't been able to figure it out from examples.

I was successful using...

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), 50f * Time.deltaTime);
```

but I would like to replicate how a sphere would actually rotate in 3d space, not just along 1 axis.

From the examples I've found, the rotation stops once it reaches the "end".

Sorry if this is a basic/noob question. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you could log `Debug.Log("Current rotation: " + transform.rotation)` while using the above `Rotate` function. This should spit out the Quaternion of the rotation in the console.

Comment: Thank you, this does write out the Quaternion, but it doesn't solve the question :/

Comment: Clarify what the "end" is.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I think the "end" was because I was using Quaternion.Lerp? It would rotate how I wanted, but stop once it reached a point. I'd like it to keep freely rotating as if it were a asteroid, basically.

Comment: But what does `transform.Rotate` have to do with `Quaternion.Lerp`? You are not lerping anything here.

Comment: I was saying that I would like to use Quaternion rotations to rotate an object, similarly to how transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), 50f * Time.deltaTime); works. I may not be explaining it right as I'm fairly new to Unity. Basically, I want to rotate an object on multiple axes much like a freely rotating asteroid. Rotating on multiple axes is key

Comment: Wouldn't multiple `transform.Rotate` calls do the same?

Comment: I have that currently in place and it seems to be feeling the effects of Gimbal lock

Comment: To avoid that you should make sure that the angular velocities (50f in this example) on each axis share no common factor.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. I'll check that out, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want the constant rotation, like an asteroid but around some custom axis then just pass this axis instead of your `Vector3(0, 0, 1)`.

This vector can be anything, like (1,2,3), but I don't remember if it has to be normalized or not.

**EDIT:**

If you need more control then you may create few quaternions and concatenate them:

```
Quaternion q1 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(10f * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.right);
Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(20f * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.forward);    
Quaternion q3 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(30f * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up);
Quaternion q = q1 * q2 * q3;
```

You just need to be aware that `q` will depend on the order of multiplication, because for quaternions `q1 * q2` is not the same as `q2 * q1`.

Comment: I'd like to rotate around multiple axes, which is why I'd like to use Quaternions (If I'm understanding them correctly). I do want to rotate like a freely rotating asteroid, basically